# Any easy way to get row count in sqldatasource without writing any code?

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I want to get row count of SqlDataSource after binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the [COMPUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708.aspx) statement.  You can put a `COMPUTE COUNT(<your PK>)` at the end of your query.

Comment: Ok how can i get from sqlDataSource?